# Gatsby scrollTo() or scrollIntoView() on markdown generated page load

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I store my content for my pages as markdown files and use the  component to link to them.

My site has a large image header which I'd like to bypass on the subpages, by scrolling past it on page load.

Since I'm working with generated pages, I do not have access to componentDidMount().

I've been through the documentation and a lot of googling but haven't found anything useful. Any advice/idea would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Are you generating the pages by exporting a function called `createPages` from `gatsby-node.js`?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I hope there is a workaround...